# Calculate amount needed to increment to get target value between certain caps

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method I can use that will calculate a chance for my game.

For example:
When the player reaches level 25 a certain thing unlocks, once they are level 225 (the max for this skill) I need it to say there is a 25% chance of the event happening.

I need a method so I can plugin the required level, max level, current level, and max chance and calculate their current skill which needs to be a constant variable but is the variable itself at level 25 and then equals 25% at level 225

I tried using

```
maxChance * (currentLevel - requiredLevel) / maxLevel - requiredLevel
```

but this method is giving the 25% chance at level 224 when it should be at 225.

I thought since the variables are 200 numbers across it could give a nice user friendly value but it seems to stop at 224.

Note: I am using percentages as decimals so .25 = 25%. Also my explaining might seem complicated because I am confused myself, if needed I can try to explain this better.

Comment: can you give a few examples of input values and expected output values?

Comment: I want when the skill unlocks at level 25 it equals X then every level it increases by that X and X = .25 at 225

Comment: This is not what i am asking for. What output do you expect for X=`0`,`1`,`24`,`25`,`100`,`101`,`224`,`225`?

Comment: @rebeliagamer .25 and under

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have 201 (not just 200) numbers: At level 25 the chance increments from 0 to X. Then at each of the subsequent 200 levels it increments by X again. So you need

```
X * 201 = maxChance
```

or, using the `requiredLevel` and `maxLevel`:

```
X * (1 + maxLevel - requiredLevel) = maxChance
```

thus

```
X = maxChance / (1 + maxLevel - requiredLevel)
```

Then for `currentLevel` the chance is

```
chance = max(currentLevel + 1 - requiredLevel, 0) * maxChance / (1 + maxLevel - requiredLevel)
       = max(currentLevel + 1 - 25, 0) * 0.25 / 201
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand how I messed that up I choose 25-225 because they should be 200 apart giving a nice user friendly, but it's 201?

Comment: Yes, I think so. There is the first increment at level 25. Then there are 200 subsequent levels, so 200 additional increments. That makes a total of 201 increments. Just assume the max level is 30. Then you get an increment when the player hits level 25, one when he hits level 26, 27, 28, 29, 30. This is a total of 6, not 5.